# Find a general expression for $\frac{p}{p+1 - \frac{p}{p+1 - \frac{p}{p+1 - \ldots}}}$ $n$ times for any value of $p \in \Bbb R$ .

Tags: fractions, continued-fractions

Find a general expression for  $\frac{p}{p+1  - \frac{p}{p+1 - \frac{p}{p+1 - \ldots}}}$ $n$ times for any value of $p \in \Bbb R$ .

**Obs:** Consider $n=1 : \frac {p}{p+1}$  and $n=2: \frac {p}{p+1 - \frac{p}{p+1}}$

I don't know how to work with continued fractions because i never worked with them before.

Any hints?

Comment: Suppose $a_{n+1} = p/(p+1-a_n)$ and $a_n = x_n/y_n, \,\,a_0=0/1$. Then $x_{n+1}/y_{n+1} = (0\cdot x_n + p\cdot y_n)/(-1\cdot x_n+(p+1)\cdot y_n).$

Comment: Evaluate the finite stages of the first few and the pattern will become obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you desire an answer to check against, I will leave one below. Be sure to solve the problem before looking at what I've written!

> As mentioned by Somos, we can define each term of this series by $$a_{n+1} = p/(p+1-a_n)\ \ \text{ with } \ \ a_0 = 0$$ The first few terms of this series are as follows: $$a_1 = \frac{p}{p+1}$$ $$a_2 = \frac{p}{p+1 - \frac{p}{p+1}} = \frac{p(p+1)}{p(p+1) + (p+1) - p} = \frac{p^2+p}{p^2+p + 1}$$ $$a_3 = \frac{p}{p+1 - \frac{p^2+p}{p^2+p + 1}} = \frac{p(p^2+p+1)}{p(p^2+p+1) + (p^2+p+1) - (p^2+p)} = \frac{p^3+p^2+p}{p^3+p^2+p+1}$$
>
>  At this point it should be clear that the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence will be: $$a_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n p^{i}}{\sum_{i=0}^n p^{i}}$$

Comment: For the limit, you can sum each geometric series.